# Count distinct customer based on last three month sales

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to get monthly count of distinct customers based on last three month Sales.

To show the result by adding current month customer count and adding last three month customer to the count as below:

- In month of APRIL ,distinct customers count of (APRIL+MARCH+FEBRUARY)
- In month of MAY,distinct customers count of (MAY+APRIL+MARCH)
- In month of JUNE,distinct customers count of (JUNE+MAY+APRIL)
- In month of JULY,distinct customers count of (JULY+JUNE+MAY)

Here what I tried:

```
SELECT  MonNumber = MONTH(h.Invoicedate) ,
            YearNumber = YEAR(h.Invoicedate) ,
            PartyCount = ( SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT s.CustomerID)
                           FROM     salesdata s
                           WHERE    s.Invoicedate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6,
                                                                  h.Invoicedate)
                                                  AND     h.Invoicedate
                         )
    FROM    salesdata h
    GROUP BY MONTH(h.Invoicedate) ,
            YEAR(h.Invoicedate)
    ORDER BY YEAR(h.Invoicedate) ,
            MONTH(h.Invoicedate)
```

---

```
| Year      | Month    |    COUNT    |
|-----------|----------|-------------|
|   2014    |    Jan   |           6 |
|   2014    |    Feb   |           6 |
|   2014    |    Mar   |           6 |
|   2014    |    Apr   |           4 |
|   2014    |    May   |           6 |
|   2014    |    Jun   |           6 |
```

[View the table on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5eff1/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

```
WITH dt AS (
-- set invoice to BOM to get one row per month  
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,InvoiceDate),0) AS InvoiceDate
  FROM salesdata
)
SELECT YEAR(dt.InvoiceDate) AS YEAR
     , MONTH(dt.InvoiceDate) AS MONTH
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) AS PARTYCOUNT
  FROM salesdata s
 INNER JOIN dt
-- Define your window
    ON s.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(MM, -2, dt.InvoiceDate)
   AND s.InvoiceDate < DATEADD(MM, 1, dt.InvoiceDate)
 GROUP BY YEAR(dt.InvoiceDate)
     , MONTH(dt.InvoiceDate)
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some aggregate function to invoicedate.

This should work: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5eff1/60/0)

```
SELECT 
   -- get the first of the current month and substract two months
   dateadd(month, -2, DATEADD(day, -day(h.Invoicedate) + 1, h.Invoicedate)) as first_of_month,
   PartyCount = ( SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT s.CustomerID)
                  FROM     salesdata s
                  WHERE    s.Invoicedate >=    dateadd(month, -2, DATEADD(day, -day(h.Invoicedate) + 1, h.Invoicedate))
                    AND    s.Invoicedate < min(dateadd(month,  1, DATEADD(day, -day(h.Invoicedate) + 1, h.Invoicedate)))
                )
FROM    salesdata h
group by
   dateadd(month, -2, DATEADD(day, -day(h.Invoicedate) + 1, h.Invoicedate))
order by 1
```

I would prefer to create a table with the month names and date ranges first and then simply use this instead.